# How to run functions from a Class in the nodes.py file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, pipeline, kedro

I want to organize the node functions by Classes in the nodes.py file. For example, functions related to cleaning data are in the "CleanData" Class, with a @staticmethod decorator, while other functions will stay in the "Other" Class, without any decorator (the names of these classes are merely representative). In the pipeline file, I tried importing the names of the classes, the names of the nodes and the following way: CleanData.function1 (which gave an error) and none of them worked. How can I call the nodes from the classes, if possible, please?

Comment: Was the error something like `TypeError: Inputs of function expected ['self', 'data', 'example_test_data_ratio'], but got ['example_iris_data', 'params:example_test_data_ratio']`?

Comment: The error said that that the names of the functions were not defined. I was calling them wrongly, your answer solved it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely certain what the error you're getting is. If you're literally trying to do `from .nodes import CleanData.function1` that won't work. Imports don't work like that in Python. If you do something like this:

`nodes.py` has:

```
class CleanData:
    def clean(arg1):
        pass
```

and `pipeline.py` has:

```
from kedro.pipeline import Pipeline, node
from .nodes import CleanData

def create_pipeline(**kwargs):
    return Pipeline(
        [
            node(
                CleanData.clean,
                "example_iris_data",
                None,
            )
        ]
    )
```

that should work.

Comment: It did work! Thank you very much! I was calling the functions in the nodes without the name of the class. Basically, I did in the imports what I should have done inside the pipeline.

Comment: That's great! :D